# Standard deviation command in SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have to implement standard deviation after retrieving data from the database in C#.

I have to retrieve a set of values from the field name `income` where the gender is either `male` or `female`

Is there ay SQL command to directly calculate the standard deviation? or should I separately calculate it using C#?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`STDEV`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190474.aspx) aggregate function:

```
select  gender
,       avg(value)
,       STDEV(value)
from    YourTable
group by
        gender
```

Comment: how can I use where command to this command? I am sorry I am weak in SQL commands.

Comment: You can add a `where` clause between the `from` and `group by`

Comment: I am getting an error `STDDEV is not a recognized built-in function name`.

Comment: Looks like a typo - should be stdev.