# STDDEV is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql

When I tried executing the following code in C# I am getting an error as `STDDEV is not a recognized built-in function name`

```
select  gender
,       avg(value)
,       stddev(value)
from    YourTable
group by
        gender
```

Comment: That's SQL, not C# code.

Comment: This makes no sense. This is an SQL statement. You cannot "execute" it directly from C#. Can you provide more code?

Comment: I mean I got the error when I tried executing the above SQL command in C# code.

Comment: You already asked about the standard deviation in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684462/standard-deviation-command-in-sql. Why did you create a new one and not simply check with the person who provided you the answer?

Comment: @SuryaManne Your problem is unrelated to C# then. I'll remove the tag.

Comment: @SuryaManne - What version of SQL Server you are using. This is only available from SQL Server 2005 +

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled Standard Deviation function.

Standard Deviation is **STDEV()**

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean **[stdev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190474.aspx)**, if you're using MS SQL