# How do I fetch a record from a table in SQL Server one by one?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server and I want to fetch data from that table one by one to calculate standard deviation of my data but I don't know how fetch data help me

Comment: You could use [cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to process row by row.. but don't.  use a function to calculate standard deviation for you. `stdev` [info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190474.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard deviation command in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684462/standard-deviation-command-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

simply try `SELECT STDEV(value) FROM yourtable`
more info [more about STDEV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190474.aspx)

hope it helped.